# Problems using CXF 2.5.2 and JBoss AS 7

Tags: web-services, cxf, jboss7.x

I'm creating a webservice using CXF 2.5.2. It runs well on tomcat. But when immigrate it to JBoss, error occurs like below:

```
14:47:42,721 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.apache.cxf.transport.ht
tp.Servlet3ContinuationProvider$Servlet3Continuation due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException
: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Servlet3ContinuationProvider$Servlet3Continuat
ion
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.
Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:
1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]

14:47:42,756 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.eclipse.jetty.continuat
ion.Servlet3Continuation$1 due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not fi
nd default constructor for class org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.Servlet3Continuation$1
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.
Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:
1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]

14:47:42,790 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.eclipse.jetty.continuat
ion.Servlet3Continuation$2 due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not fi
nd default constructor for class org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.Servlet3Continuation$2
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.
Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:
1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]

14:47:42,929 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."PocWS
-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."PocWS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL:
 Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "PocWS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.
Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:
1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: JBAS011466: PersistenceProvider 'org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderI
mpl' not found
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.lookupProvider(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:546)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.addPuService(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:279)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.handleWarDeployment(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:19
4)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.deploy(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:118)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.
Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        ... 5 more
```

Piece of my service code is:

```
@WebService
public interface UserService {

    @WebMethod
    public void addNewUser( @WebParam(name="userName") String userName, @WebParam(name="address")  String address, @WebParam(name="phoneNum")  String phoneNum);
```

And i configured the service using xml like:

```
<bean id="UserService" class="com.hp.poc.service.UserServiceImpl" />

    <!-- WebService -->
    <jaxws:endpoint id="UserWSEndPoint" implementor="#UserService"
        address="/userws">
    </jaxws:endpoint>
```

Could u please give me some help?

Answer (score 0):

Check your dependencies, if the version of your jar are same as your jboss lib folders, i.e the cxf jars in modules folder of jboss should be the same declared in your pom.xml or in your classpath.

also exclude any jetty dependencies from cxf bundles. i.e:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

Finally you will be left with:

```
10:27:00,424 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Servlet3ContinuationProvider$Servlet3Continuation due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Servlet3ContinuationProvider$Servlet3Continuation
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
```

I believe this is because of the default jars that comes from Jboss check:

[Spring3.2 and jboss as 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786685/spring3-2-and-jboss-as-7)