# Spring3.2 and jboss as 7

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss7.x

How to resolve this warn? If i use Spring 3.2 i am see this warn:

> 14:24:19,014 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest

Comment: Do you resolved this problem?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Apparently this is "normal", everything should still work. Likely there's an (anonymous) inner class in `StandardServletAsyncWebRequest`.

See also [Applicaiton is deployed in JBoss7.0.2 Final (Arc ) but failed to in 7.1.1 Final (Brontes)](https://community.jboss.org/message/760558#760558) and [metadata-complete="true" not respected](https://community.jboss.org/message/739794). Basically it's just a warning, everything is fine.

Comment: I have gotten quite a few of these warnings in several applications. So far, they have not caused any problems.  I have just been ignoring them for now, which seems to be what most people are doing.

Comment: As Philippe says, it seems to be "normal", the applications (at least in my case) work correctly. Currently, I hide those comments using a filter as explained [here](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2421).

Comment: @Philippe - if it is "normal" then what is JBoss so annoyed about? What does one lose when this "optional" component is not installed, as JBoss says?

Comment: @wavicle I'm not entirely sure. I can only assume it's related to component injection eg. if you wanted to have an instance of an anonymous inner class injected somewhere it would fail.

Answer (score 10):

To expand aloplop85's link, you can ignore this message. You might want to suppress it because it is distracting (in my opinion, a working application should never normally print stack traces in the log). The instructions are here http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2421, short version is to add the following text into the config file (e.g.`standalone.xml`):

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.0">
      <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
          <!-- levels, formatters etc. -->
          <filter>
              <not>
                  <match pattern="JBAS011054"/>
              </not>
          </filter>
      </console-handler>
      <!-- and the same for other handlers -->
  </subsystem>
```

For JBoss 7.2.0, the syntax is a bit different:

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.2">
      <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
         <!-- levels, formatters etc. -->
         <filter value='not(match("JBAS011054"))' />
      </console-handler>
      <!-- and the same for other handlers -->
  </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 8):

This is how I suppressed it in my jboss-as-7.1.1

updated configuration/standalone.xml as

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
      <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
          <filter>
              <not>
                  <match pattern="JBAS011054|JBAS011006"/>
              </not>
          </filter>
      </console-handler>
  </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 6):

JBoss warns you when can't find no-args constructor for a class.
In this case, there is no no-arg constructor for this Spring class.
Just this one:

`public StandardServletAsyncWebRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(request, response);
    }`

No problem with that..That will work..

Comment: This looks like a non-standard JBoss requirement rather than a Spring bug. Is that correct?