# Resteasy JBoss7 spring-3.2.0-M1

Tags: spring, jboss7.x, spring-3

I try to run web-service client on jboss7 and I get strange exception

```
WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
```

I read more than one compliant but no one resolution

Comment: Spring 3.2.0 FINAL is out, since last week, may you first try to update.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring3.2 and jboss as 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786685/spring3-2-and-jboss-as-7)