# JBAS011006 Not installing optional component StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to exception DeploymentUnitProcessingException

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jboss7.x

Since, Spring 3.2 GA release is out I wanted to upgrade my Spring 3.1.2 application to the newest release. The application runs on JBoss 7.1.1.Final. Everything else went fine except that I get the below JBoss error message which I find annoying (though the app runs ok). Any idea?

```
15:50:06,865 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
```

Comment: don't use title as question body

Comment: This has been [answered on SO here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786685/spring3-2-and-jboss-as-7

Answer (score 3):

In order to suppress this warning message add following lines to your Jboss config (standalone.xml if you're using it in standalone mode)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.1">
...
    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <filter>
                    <not>
                        <match pattern="JBAS011006"/>
                    </not>
                </filter>
...
```

As you can check in [javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.html), there's no default constructor for this class.
Since it's just a warning and everything goes fine, you can ignore it.